# Why does electromagnetism have torsion, whereas gravity does not?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, gauge-theory

Why don't we use torsion-free covariant derivatives for QM, even though we already do so in the case of GR?

- In general relativity, we use the Levi-civita connection, a torsion-free connection compatible with some Lorentz fibre metric on the tangent bundle. (represents a structure-group reduction $O(3,1)<GL(4,\mathbb R)$).
- In electromagnetism, we use a connection compatible with some hermitian fibre metric on the complex line bundle. (represents a structure-group reduction $U(1)<GL(1,\mathbb C)$). Note here, that I am taking a minimalist viewpoint, where I am starting with the endowed structure of QM and trying to introduce EM naturally by making the geometry of the bundle a dynamical variable.

I looked at an interesting article, *Connection between Einstein and Yang-Mills equations*, which unfortunately stumbled when it came to this comparison:

[image]

Is this because we can measure torsion in a relativistic and gravitational setting, but not in a quantum mechanical laboratory? I'm really looking for the physical significance of this, perhaps explained in terms of observers.

Comment: The version of general relativity with torsion is called Einstein-Cartan theory and it may very well be implemented in nature, we simply haven't been able to measure a torsion term, yet, but until quite recently we said that same thing about the cosmological constant. There are quite a few people who are thinking about Einstein-Cartan because it would, for instance, remove singularities from black hole solutions and the big bang.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "measuring a torsion term", and explain, perhaps, why this is not possible in a quantum-mechanical setting?

Comment: Aside: Does OP know what the physical significance of the Yang-Mills torsion is? (I do not.)

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify: The Hilbert space of wave functions for a particle is naturally the space of sections of some hermitian line bundle $(\mathcal L,\nabla)$, where the Hilbert space structure is derived from the hermitian structure (a smooth fibre-wise hermitian inner-product). I have not mentioned classical mechanics, or Maxwell theory, at all. - I'll edit the question to make the context clear.

Comment: I am not an expert in GR, but from what I have heard from Einstein-Cartan experts during a one day seminar about it, it should couple trough a fourth (?) order term to electromagnetism and magnetic spins. This seems to lead to a strong phenomenological sensitivity for high-energy x-ray and gamma ray energies, i.e. one should see spectral line effect in neutron star emissions, or so. The problem seems to be that this very effect seems to limit the coupling strength quite considerably based on available observations. You can treat this as hearsay.

Comment: My 2 cents that are probably not satisfying to you: we don't need to eliminate the torsion because none of the reasons why we eliminate torsion in GR have any relevance here.

Comment: Sure - but there might still be reasons to eliminate torsion in EM, even if they are distinct from the reasons in GR. Yang-Mills torsion most likely represents quantum-mechanical gauge-freedom, in the case of U(1).

Comment: Being able to measure/eliminate torsion would imply that the phase of a wavefunction is actually a physical quantity. But this is all my rough intuition, and probably wrong. This is why I have asked this question - I am curious to know the truth.

Comment: @David That's interesting. I'd like to see your (rough) reasoning.

Comment: The phase is a scalar. Why would an anti-symmetric term change a scalar any more than a symmetric term does?

Comment: This question does not make sense. Without a [solder form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solder_form), you cannot even *define* torsion, and canonical $\mathrm{U}(1)$ electromagnetism (or any generic gauge theory for that matter, or a generic Hermitian line bundle) does *not* come with such a solder form, since the gauge structure is *unrelated* to the tangent structure of the base manifold. So, you cannot claim that EM has torsion because you *cannot define torsion for it in the first place*, and hence I don't understand what you might be asking.